# MySQL - Select from table 1 if second table is empty or not not empty

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

Hi I try to show data from two tables, but second table is empty

```
SELECT ST.* , E.data, E.status
FROM `students` ST
INNER JOIN `table2` E ON E.id_student=ST.id_student
WHERE    ST.class='$class' AND E.data LIKE '$year-$month-%'
ORDER BY ST.surname, ST.name, E.data
```

what query I can use for my request (if second table is empty I need only students list if not I need the result), I know that Inner JOIN shows records only if it exist

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN`; you'll get `NULL` for the fields of `table2` when a row matching the row from `students` does not exist.

Comment: When LEFT JOIN, move outer table's WHERE conditions to it's ON clause. (Otherwise still inner join.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Left join will do it for you.

```
SELECT ST.* , E.data, E.status
FROM `students` ST
LEFT JOIN `table2` E
ON E.id_student=ST.id_student and E.data LIKE '$year-$month-%'
WHERE ST.class='$class'
ORDER BY ST.surname, ST.name, E.data
```

It will give you ST data values even if E data is empty. Of course you have to take care of the null values in the columns from the empty table

[image: Left Join diagram]

Inner join only gives you information when the data is present on both tables

[image: Inner join diagram]

Edit: jarlh suggestion in order to work properly

Comment: When LEFT JOIN, move outer table's WHERE conditions to it's ON clause. (Otherwise still inner join.)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **LEFT JOIN** to fetch the data from first table and matched data of second table.

```
SELECT ST.*, E.data, E.status
FROM `students` ST
LEFT JOIN `table2` E ON E.id_student=ST.id_student AND E.data LIKE '$year-$month-%'
WHERE ST.class='$class'
ORDER BY ST.surname, ST.name, E.data
```

Answer (score 0):

As Saharsh Shah states (sorry, cannot comment), you have to use LEFT JOIN,  and you could also add IFNULL code, so that for example, if you want the ST.name ST.surname and ST.class values use:

```
    SELECT  IFNULL(ST.name,''),IFNULL(ST.surname,''),IFNULL(ST.class,''), E.data, E.status
   FROM `students` ST
    LEFT JOIN `table2` E ON E.id_student=ST.id_student AND E.data LIKE '$year-$month-%'
    WHERE ST.class='$class'
    ORDER BY ST.surname, ST.name, E.data
```

So that you don't have NULL values on your selected fields.